# Why am I experiencing endless connection timeouts using quarkus microprofile reactive rest client

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

At some point of my quarkus app life (under kubernetes) it begins getting endless connection timeouts from multiple different hosts (timeout configured to be 1 second). As of this point the app never recovers until I restart the k8s pod.

These endless connection timeouts are not due to the hosts since other apps in the cluster do not suffer from this, also a restart of my app fixes the problem.

I am declaring multiple hosts(base-uri) through the quarkus application.properties. (maybe its using a single vertx/netty event-loop and it's wrong?)

Comment: When you get the timeouts, can you do a thread dump? Do you see any exceptions in the logs about blocked threads?

Comment: If you can get a thread dump and something looks wrong, please open an issue in our tracker there: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues .

Comment: I made a thread dump but everything looks ok. no blocked threads. Also in the logs. Just suddenly, endless timeouts. Other pods - running the same app - are running smoothly. Something seems to be stucked at the connections level...

Comment: When this problem happens, would it be possible to access the terminal inside the running container and check the network connection with these hosts? Perhaps the network problem could be on the pod level and not in Quarkus.